# Asp.net adding data to database from forms using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

so i was making a asp.net project and after setting up the registration page, it was time to add the user entered items in the database so i created a new database called "myData"
after validating all the inputs, i wrote the code below:

```
If Page.IsPostBack = False Then



            Dim sqlCon As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myData").ConnectionString)
            sqlCon.Open()
            Dim str As String
            str = "insert into users(username,password,email) VALUES('" + first + "','" + password + "','" + email + "')"

            Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand(str, sqlcon)
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()





        Session.Item("name") = txtUsername.Text
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx")
        sqlcon.Close()
        MsgBox("Account Created with Success")
        End if
```

every time i run the page i get an error (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.) for sqlcon 
is there anything i can do to avoid this error?
any help would be appreciate it.

Comment: Do not use your code as is on a public facing server. You are wide open to a SQL injection attack. PLease read the folloing article on how to use a parametized query to help prevent such an attack: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Parameterized-queries-to-prevent-SQL-Injection-Attacks-in-SQL-Server.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would utilize the [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) statment to encapsulate your database usage. This will dispose of your objects correctly. As previously mentioned your redirect should happen last when not using the optional boolean argument. I have also parametized your query to help prevent SQL injection attacks.

```
If Page.IsPostBack = False Then

     Using sqlCon As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myData").ConnectionString)
           sqlCon.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "insert into users(username,password,email) VALUES(@username,@password,@email)"

        Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand(str, sqlcon)
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", first)
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password)
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email)
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


        Session.Item("name") = txtUsername.Text
    End Using

    MsgBox("Account Created with Success")
    Response.Redirect("default.aspx")


    End if
```

Also make sure if you are storing passwords, to store them salted and encypted: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm.

Just to cover myself....I'm mainly a C# guy and my VB is a little rusty so there may be a couple of  syntax errors to iron out.

Answer (score 0):

Any codes after `Response.Redirect` with no Boolean argument indicate that the response should end and it stops executing by throwing a System.Threading.

therefore you need to close the connection before `Response.Redirect`. 
so your sqlcon object reference not set to an instance of an object